# WinForms WebBrowser ExecCommand CreateLink converts link to lowercase

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I created an application that uses a HTML editor based on the WebBrowser control that's included in WinForms. When a link is added via the following function

```
public void InsertLink(string url)
{
  webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("CreateLink", false, url);
}
```

the result is `<a href="http://youtu.be/jaxlk969mtq">text</a>` when it should have been `<a href="http://youtu.be/JAXlk969MtQ">text</a>` (with upper case letters). Is this default behavior? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to add a `<a>` element to body or another element instead of `ExecCommand`:

```
HtmlElement o = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("a");
o.SetAttribute("href", url);
o.InnerText = "Text";
webBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(o);// or anHtmlElement.AppenChild(o);
```